# ISAPI webbroker requestcontentfields is empty (length = 0)

Tags: delphi, iis, datasnap, webbroker

I created a WebBroker application using the Wizard. I changed the default action's code so it looks like this:

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  i := Request.ContentLength;
  Response.Content :=
    '<html>' +
    '<head><title>DataSnap Server</title></head>' +
    '<body>DataSnap Server x' +
    Request.ContentFields.Text + 'x' + IntToStr(i) + 'x' +
    '</body>' +
    '</html>';
end;
```

I deployed the dll under IIS (6.2 - Server 2012) and tested the dll using a webbrowser.

http://localhost/MapServer/Mapserver.dll/?param1=hello

Just for good measure I tried

http://localhost/MapServer/Mapserver.dll/?param1="hello"

The browser outputs

> DataSnap Server xx0x

in both cases.

It appears the `Request.ContentFields` is not being populated by the call from the browser.

Is this issue specific to a particular version of Delphi and/or IIS? What am I not understanding?

I have tried both Seattle and Berlin, the result is the same.
Thanks

P.S. I also used the wizard to make a stand-alone WebBroker. It doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some really deep Google searching, I found the answer: (Note that while the Embarcadero documentation states that `Request.ContentFields` contains the contents of fields "when the MethodType is mtPost", the practically useless documentation for `Request.QueryFields` says nothing about `mtGet`)

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  i := Length(Request.QueryFields.Text);
  Response.Content :=
    '<html>' +
    '<head><title>DataSnap Server</title></head>' +
    '<body>DataSnap Server x' +
    Request.QueryFields.Text + 'x' + IntToStr(i) + 'x' +
    '</body>' +
    '</html>';
end;
```